# PHP DomDocument - how to append string containing html tags?

Tags: php, html, dom, tags, domdocument

I have a method that is returning those typea of strings:

```
string(6) "<math>"
string(12) " <semantics>"
string(8) "  <mrow>"
string(29) "   <mi>A</mi><mrow><mo>(</mo>"
string(14) "    <mi>T</mi>"
string(27) "   <mo>)</mo></mrow></mrow>"
string(13) " </semantics>"
string(7) "</math>"
```

My goal is to append this to a DOMDocument. Is there a possibility to check if I have a tag in my string, so the tag should be added as child, not node value.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do mean convert them all to an HTML node and append them to an DOMDocument node?

Comment: Right, I just got an idea: put them in a single striing and use the domdocument loadhtml

Comment: Good, I am preparing a solution for you; could you tell me are you calling your method in loop and each time it returns one of the strings or it just return an array of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help you

```
//I assume the name of your method is "getStringsNodes()" and it returns the array of strings
$string_array = getStringNodes();
$string_array = array_map('trim', $string_array);
$string_xml = implode('', $string_array);
$new_nodes = new DomDocument();
$new_nodes->loadXML($string_xml);
$first_node = $new_node->getElementsByTagName('math')->item(0);

//I assume the parent XML container is $owner_xml
$owner_xml = new DomDocument();
$owner_xml->loadXML('<sample><parent_node></parent_node></sample>'); //convert this to whatever you need
$node = $owner_xml->importNode($first_node, true);
$parent_node = $owner_xml->getElementsByTagName('parent_node')->item(0);
$parent_node->appendChild($node);
```

I hope this helps you.